# How to load 900k records from azure Kusto to dataverse using ADF pipeline

Tags: copy, azure-data-factory, dataverse, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to create an ADF pipeline for copying data from azure data explorer Kusto to dataverse, from my source side table has 0.9 million records.

I'm trying to run the pipeline it is failed.

How to copy 900k records to sink side?

How much data load in single pipeline?

Comment: How much data load in single pipeline? Is there possible to load 9 Lac records?

Comment: Please use **internationally understood** measures - thousands, millions, billions ...

Comment: 0.9 Millions records

Comment: you mentioned pipeline was failed. What was the error that it gave?

Comment: Pipeline error:(Source connection was forcibly closed by host), this error i get, only 0.8 million records loaded

Comment: Is it the same when trying with small data from same source? Can you try by copying the 0.9 million data to Blob and check if it results same or not?

Comment: I don't have permission on blob storage

Comment: Failed happened on 'Source' side. type=Kusto.Data.Exception.KustoClientStreamReadException,Message=Kusto client failed reading the result stream from the service: 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Comment: Is Linked service connection working? Is it working for small amount of data?

Comment: Yes linked service connection working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257098/discussion-between-rakesh-govindula-and-chinnu).

Answer (score 0):

> Kusto client failed reading the result stream from the service: 'Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The below might be the reasons for the above error.

- It can be because of Firewall blockage or temporary network issue. Publish your resources and try again. Go to **Networking** of the ADX cluster and make sure it checked on the right option like below.

  [image]
- As the data is large, try by scaling up your cluster memory and check.

  [image]

After these, make sure the **No truncation** is checked in the copy activity source. This allows to copy more than 0.5 million records.

[image]

I have followed the same steps, and you can see I am able to copy data up to 1 million records without any error.

[image]